# How/where is sbrk used within malloc.c?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, malloc, sbrk

I have read in Advanced Unix Programming (and also in a few other books) that Linux `malloc()` uses the Linux system call `sbrk()` to request memory from the operating system.

I am looking at the glibc `malloc.c` code and I can see many mentions of `sbrk()` in the comments, but not referred to directly in the code.

How/where is `sbrk()` referred to/used when `malloc()` requests memory from the OS?

(This could be a general misunderstanding on my part of how system calls are made from the C runtime library. If so, I would be interested to know how they are made??)

Comment: While I'm not sure about the actual location of `sbrk`, there's nothing different between a system call in C and a function, with the exception that control is completely managed by the operating system until the system call completes.

Comment: [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) tend to become rusty and obsolete. There are good reasons (multi-threading) to use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) only.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch could you briefly elaborate on such reasons?

Comment: Read the man page. `sbrk` is removed from latest Posix standard.

Answer (score 8):

Glibc's [malloc.c](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/malloc/malloc.c) requests more memory by calling the function stored in the `__morecore` global function pointer (the call actually uses the macro `MORECORE` which expands to `__morecore`). By default, this holds the address of function `__default_morecore`, which is defined in [morecore.c](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/malloc/morecore.c). This function calls `sbrk`.

Note that some `malloc` implementations may use `mmap` to get more memory instead of `sbrk`.

Comment: Cool- have found it. The comment in morecore.c says: "Allocate INCREMENT more bytes of data space, and return the start of data space". So if I want 100 bytes of data I call malloc() which ends up calling the function in morecore.c, which calls sbrk() and this function returns a pointer to the beginning of the 100 bytes? Or does sbrk() get used before main() is called to allocate the whole heap for the process?

Comment: @user997112 The heap size is not known in advance, so `sbrk` will be called by `malloc`. But it won't translate 1 to 1, because `malloc` will probably request larger blocks of memory from `sbrk` and then divide them, and it can also return previously freed memory to the caller without needing `sbrk`.

Comment: So all sbrk does is to accept a request for memory, given a size and provide a pointer to it. Isnt this VERY similar to what malloc does()? In other words, what is the purpose of malloc() if sbrk does this? Just to put a load of error-handling in?

Comment: `sbrk()` doesn't know which parts of the memory are still in use, as there's no equivalent to free; malloc handles recycling of memory blocks that have been `malloc()`ed and `free()`d.